# Is .NET Core truly multi platform?

Tags: .net

This question may be simple to some, but is something I can't find anything about.
If I write a program with .NET Core on Windows, can the same output file (that as far as I know is not a literal executable file) work on Linux?
If .NET is supposed to work like Java, then this should be simple. But if that's true, why most .NET Core programs made on Windows can't run on Linux?

Comment: You should internet search " netstandard vs netcoreapp " ... I'll get you started : https://code-maze.com/differences-between-net-framework-net-core-and-net-standard/

Comment: "But if that's true, why most .NET Core programs made on Windows can't run on Linux?" Where did you get that assertion from? Basically it depends on what the application is - if you write a WPF or WinForms app with .NET, then no, you can't use that on Linux. But if you write  console app, class library or web app, then yes, you can use the same binaries. (It's actually more complex than that as you can publish target-specific binaries, but the result of a plain "dotnet build" can generally be used elsewhere...)

Comment: https://dotnetcore.show/episode-92-a-few-things-i-wish-i-knew-before-writing-net-on-linux/

Comment: @JonSkeet So, .NET Core is just a limited framework when talking about other OSes? If the most useful libs are still Windows only, this makes the whole thing only usable on Windows and servers, excluding other desktop platforms.

Comment: I saw something about XAML but this seems to not be the standard.

Comment: Firstly, .NET Core itself is old hat - the last .NET Core release was 3.1. These days it's just ".NET" (.NET 5, .NET 6 and .NET 7). It's limited in terms of not being able to do WPF and WinForms, but describing those as "the most useful libs" is *very* opinion-based. If you want to write a multi-platform UI, you can use MAUI - which supports (IIRC) Windows, Android, iOS and macOS. Not Linux yet, but hopefully in the future.

Comment: @JonSkeet If MAUI don't support Linux, then there's no utility to me. I will just stick with gtk.

Comment: And that's fine - but please be aware that "no utility to you" isn't the same as saying "most .NET Core programs can't run on Linux" or "most useful libs are still Windows only". Lots and lots of .NET code is running on Linux.

Comment: Although there are other frameworks you could use, of course: https://avaloniaui.net/ for example.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that most .NET Core (or now just .NET) code is actually web application code, which *does* run on Linux. Likewise any console apps that don't use Win32 APIs should be fine on Linux too. (.NET is a nice environment in which to write tooling, particularly now that small console apps are briefer with [top-level statements in C# 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements).) Class libraries like my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) library work fine on Linux.

However, given your comments, it sounds like you're actually only interested in running desktop applications on Linux - in which case no, you can't run WPF or WinForms applications using .NET on Linux. You *can* run [Avalonia UI](https://avaloniaui.net/) and [Uno Platform](https://platform.uno/) apps on Linux, I believe - and I expect that [MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui) will *eventually* support Linux too.

If you were really looking to run WPF, WinForms or MAUI apps on Linux, then you'll be disappointed - but I would suggest you don't write off the entire .NET ecosystem just because it doesn't meet your specific need right now.